# Trying to get information back from Javascript in WKWebView (using KINWebBrowser)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

So I am trying to get a value back from the browser window after it is generated by some client side code.

Here's what I have:

```
class WebBrowserViewController: KINWebBrowserViewController, NavigationProtocol, KINWebBrowserDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    let contentController = WKUserContentController();
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "callbackHandler"
    )
...

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController!, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print("Debug message got here")
    if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {
        print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")
    }
}
```

Now I am 100% sure this is not all of the code I need.

Using this as an [example](http://onebigfunction.com/ios/2016/12/14/iOS-javascript-communication/), it seems to me like I need to add this configuration to my browser somehow:

```
self.webView = WKWebView(frame: webFrame, configuration: config)
```

The big problem here is that this is for straight WkWebView, and the project I am working with is using KinWebBrowser. Rather than start from scratch with a whole new implementation, it seems there's a way to extend KinWebBrowser, but I'm not totally familiar with Swift syntax yet, or Objective-C, and it seems that KinWebBrowser is written in Objective-C.

Here's what I think is the relevant interface definition for KinWebBrowser:

```
@interface KINWebBrowserViewController : UIViewController <WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>

#pragma mark - Public Properties

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <KINWebBrowserDelegate> delegate;

// The main and only UIProgressView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIProgressView *progressView;

// The web views
// Depending on the version of iOS, one of these will be set
@property (nonatomic, strong) WKWebView *wkWebView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *uiWebView;

- (id)initWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);

#pragma mark - Static Initializers

/*
 Initialize a basic KINWebBrowserViewController instance for push onto navigation stack

 Ideal for use with UINavigationController pushViewController:animated: or initWithRootViewController:

 Optionally specify KINWebBrowser options or WKWebConfiguration
 */

+ (KINWebBrowserViewController *)webBrowser;
+ (KINWebBrowserViewController *)webBrowserWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

So how do I extend KinWebBrowser in such a way that when I call this script:

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");
```

I will get whatever I pass into `.postMessage`?

My ultimate goal is to get a string or other data from the web into my iOS app after it is generated in a web browser window.

Comment: As I understand, you want to get data from webView when doing something from native side by calling `window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("Hello from JavaScript");`. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, correct, I want to get information from native side back to the app

Comment: Where will you trigger action to get information? clicking on a button on webView or do an action from app?

Comment: It’ll happen as part of the login or initialization process. Not super relevant though.

Comment: It's hard to say what you are asking for. Can you explain it more detail?

Comment: I just need to get data back from the web browser like in the example link, just using KinWebBrowser

Comment: I need to know when you want to get data back. Maybe when webView is loaded or when you click on something on webView or when you do an action from the app. Will have another solution with each case

Comment: Action from the app. It would be on an event. Like in the example. Basically if I call that specific method after defining it, it should get the data into the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you are doing everything right way but you don't know how to execute script from your app. To resolve it, you can use [evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) method.

```
wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript("window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(\"Hello from JavaScript\");", completionHandler: nil)
```

For more detail, you can check [my sample project](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/wkwebview-handle-message).

Comment: How is this solution using KinWebBrowser?

Comment: Oh sorry didn’t see the sample. I’ll take a look

Comment: No problem, let me know if it's not suitable for your problem or you need something else.

Comment: I haven’t had time to test it today. I’ll be testing it soon

Comment: So what version did you make this for? My xcode is choking on it, saying incompatible project version.

Comment: I should be able to at least look at your demo swift files to see what you did though

Comment: I use XCode 9.3 to create it. Maybe it’s the problem

Comment: Ah, I'm using 9.2 for the specific backwards compatibility I need for this app until I upgrade it. That's likely it. I think I have a good idea what you did from your code though, I'll test it in mine and report back

Comment: Yep, I got data back from the JS, I think we're good! Thank you.

Comment: Great! Welcome my friend.